# Bootstrap Scroll Spy Not working - highlights the last section only?

Tags: scrollspy

Scroll Spy, why aren't you working? My Body has not 100% height, I've set my data attributes correctly and just can understand why you are not working !

http://wildenmedia.com/index.php/products

I believe I've followed bootstrap docs correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It's `#content` you want to spy on:

```
$('#content').scrollspy();
```

Comment: Yeah, I can see that you have edited the page you posted previously.